# How to disable auto-reply from users email when mailing via Bot

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have bot for mailing some info to my subscribers via info@domain.com. After sending all mailing, from users comes auto-replied letter like "they got mail, and will answer soon"~something like this.

Question is: `How to stop or disable that auto-replied letter from users?`

P.S: my mail box filled with auto-replied letters((

I want to get letter when the users himself sends.

> P.S: before I used [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) service to mailing, so while using [sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/) I never got auto-replied mails. Now it's expensive for me((, so I decided to use just [yandex.com](https://yandex.com/support/mail/mail-clients.html) service.

Comment: You simple can't without hacking their postboxes ;)

Comment: Do what everyone else does and send from a noreply

Comment: @BugFinder, so I have no choice then to create email no-reply@domain.com?

Comment: no, thats the point the noreply doesnt have to exist, just make sure the headers are sent out as noreply.. (it doesnt have to have the words no reply in it, but it is the kinda norm for it to indicate, dont send mails)

Comment: Thanks for a way to annoy spammers :)
Im starting responding for every email :D

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik :D, yeah this is good way, but we are don't gonna spam our users, just send useful things)))))))))))))

Comment: @BugFinder okei thanks